# Python Won't Enter Try/Except In For Loop On 50th Iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, iteration, try-catch

First off I want to apologize to everyone who's about to read this code... I know it's a mess.

For anyone who is able to decipher it: I have a list of ~16,500 website URL's that I am scraping and then using googles NLP to categorize. The list of URL's is created with the following chunk of code, as far as I can tell nothing is broken here.

```
url_list = open("/Users/my_name/Documents/Website Categorization and Scrapper Python/url_list copy", "r")
indexed_url_list = url_list.readlines()
clean_url_list = []

clean_url_list = [x[:-1] for x in indexed_url_list]
```

When I print the length of this list it correctly gives me the count of ~16,500.

The main block of code is as follows:

```
for x in clean_url_list:

print('1')
url = x
print('1.1')
try:
    
    r = scraper.get(url, headers = headers,)
    
    print('1.2')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    print('1.3')
    title = soup.find('title').text
    print('1.4')
    description = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'description'})["content"]
    print('2')
    if "content" in str(description):
        description = description.get("content")
    else:
        description = ""


    h1 = soup.find_all('h1')
    h1_all = ""
    for x in range (len(h1)):
        if x ==  len(h1) -1:
            h1_all = h1_all + h1[x].text
        else:
            h1_all = h1_all + h1[x].text + ". "


    paragraphs_all = ""
    paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
    for x in range (len(paragraphs)):
        if x ==  len(paragraphs) -1:
            paragraphs_all = paragraphs_all + paragraphs[x].text
        else:
            paragraphs_all = paragraphs_all + paragraphs[x].text + ". "



    h2 = soup.find_all('h2')
    h2_all = ""
    for x in range (len(h2)):
        if x ==  len(h2) -1:
            h2_all = h2_all + h2[x].text
        else:
            h2_all = h2_all + h2[x].text + ". "



    h3 = soup.find_all('h3')
    h3_all = ""
    for x in range (len(h3)):
        if x ==  len(h3) -1:
            h3_all = h3_all + h3[x].text
        else:
            h3_all = h3_all + h3[x].text + ". "

    allthecontent = ""
    allthecontent = str(title) + " " + str(description) + " " + str(h1_all) + " " + str(h2_all) + " " + str(h3_all) + " " + str(paragraphs_all)
    allthecontent = str(allthecontent)[0:999]
    print(allthecontent)


except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

When I run this it successfully categorizes the first 49 URL's, but ALWAYS stops on the 50th, no matter what URL it is. No error is thrown, and even if it did the try/except should handle it. Using the print statements to debug it seems to not enter the "try" section on the 50th iteration for whatever reason and it's always the 50th iteration

Any help would be much appreciated and I hope you have some good eye wash to wipe away the code you just had to endure.

Comment: `clean_url_list = [x[:-1] for x in indexed_url_list]`: `x[:-1]` means take every element in `x` **except the last**. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Kraigolas this is to remove \n from each url string in the indexed_url_list if I recall

Comment: Could the problem be your loading in? I notice you don't print `clean_url_list`. How do you know it's missing the last one?

Comment: Also: `url_list = open("/Users/my_name/Documents/Website Categorization and Scrapper Python/url_list copy", "r")` you never seem to close this file. If instead you use a `with open(..., 'r') as ...)` block, the file is closed automatically. This is noted as "good practice" in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: @Kraigolas regarding the clean_url_list, would missing the last one matter? the list length is 16000 + Urls so even if it is missing the last one that wouldn't explain why it stops only on the 50th iteration. And I will try the second recommendation and report what happens

Comment: closing the file didn't seem to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I helped look at this at work. The actual issue was a bad 50th url that would not return. Adding a timeout allowed the code to escape the try/catch block and move on to the next url in a manageable fashion.

```py
try:
   r = scraper.get(url, headers = headers, timeout=5)
except:
   continue # handle next url in list
```